# Organize helper in sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is there a way to structure code in a helper in sails.js v1.0?

Currently I have something like that:

```
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Example helper that does three things',

  description: '',

  inputs: {},

  exits: {},

  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    const doFirstThing = function () {
      // do something
    };

    const doSecondThing = function () {
      // do something
    };

    const doThirdThing = function () {
      // do something
    };

    doFirstThing();
    doSecondThing();
    doThirdThing();
  },
};
```

The three functions `doFirstThing` `doSecondThing` `doThirdThing` each have about 15 lines of code. Right now, the code is pretty hard to read. Is there a way to put there functions below the fn function or structure it in any other way that is more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always define the function outside and assign it to your `module.exports` object later. You can also define `doFirstThing` and the other two functions separately if they do not use the closure variables of the `doEverything` function

```
async function doEverything(inputs, exits) {
    const doFirstThing = function () {
        // do something
    };

    const doSecondThing = function () {
        // do something
    };

    const doThirdThing = function () {
        // do something
    };

    doFirstThing();
    doSecondThing();
    doThirdThing();
}
module.exports = {

    friendlyName: 'Example helper that does three things',

    description: '',

    inputs: {},

    exits: {},

    fn: doEverything
};
```